# jquery calendar not working in ipad as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I am using jquery-UI for the datepicker calendar working in desktop but when i saw in tablet and mobile version (Firefox) I am not getting date picker instead i am getting list of description.  I have included corresponding files.

Here is the HTML code which I am using

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <br/>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_dob" name="txt_dob" />
      <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code.

```
//date_picker
$("#txt_dob").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: false,
});
```

[image]

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance
mahadevan

Answer (score 0):

The problem was bootstrap css.  In my bootstrap i have something like this

```
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Application No"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Academic Career"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Major"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Major Status"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Application Status"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Submitted On"; }
td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Valid Till"; }
td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Recruter"; }
td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Remarks"; }
td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Action"; }
```

So that is the reson the value is adding in all the td and i am getting like the image.

I found and I solved it.

Thank you so much.

Regards
Mahadevan